# Get object name in callback function for VBA object?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Let's say I have a userform with a command button named `cmd_1`.

For purposes of my application, I have a lot of validation I would like to do on this click - see [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/224077/52929) for some discussion about what I am attempting to do. Basically I am hoping to implement a single callback function with logical rules I check, based on the calling object's name, to determine the eligibility of that control's actions.

This would look something like:

```
private function isValid(p_controlName as string) as boolean
    'logical checks based on the the value of p_controlName
    'returning true/false as appropriate
end function
```

and I would be using it something like this

```
Private Sub cmd_1_Click()
    if isValid("cmd_1") = false then exit sub
End Sub
```

Now I am going to be putting this into a *lot* of UI callbacks (I don't like thinking about how many). I would rather avoid having to tediously add the name of the control to each callback. I would very, VERY much prefer do something like:

```
Private Sub cmd_1_Click()
    'this is not valid syntax
    if isValid(ThisControl.name) = false then exit sub
End Sub
```

This is better for a whole variety of reasons, ease of implementation, consistency, less likely for errors, etc.

However I cannot seem to find a way to get the name of the calling control within a callback function.

- Is there some way to get the name of a control in VBA code from a callback function to use as an argument like I am trying?

Answer (score 3):

If it's only button click event handlers, then `Screen.ActiveControl.Name` should get you what you want - `Screen.ActiveControl` returns the control with the keyboard focus, and a command button takes the keyboard focus on being clicked.

Comment: Hmm this seems likely to be exactly what I need. I'll probably be perpetually paranoid that `ActiveControl` would return an invalid control for whatever reason, though...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use a callback function for each, with a parameter based on the control name or information that you need, and make the controls each have:

```
Dim rect As Control
Dim coll As Form

Set coll = Forms("myForm")
For Each rect In coll.Controls
    If rect.ControlType = acRectangle Then
        rect.OnClick = "=myCallbackFunction(" & param & ")"
    End If
Next rect
```

myCallbackFunction is just a function on the same form as the control, or a public function in a module.

I've done this where each rectangle (up to 100, pre-generated at height 0 on my form) is moved and made visible based on a recordset, then they have this onclick event setup based on an ID from the recordset. In my case it selects a different subform record to match the rectangle clicked.

Don
Have a great day